# How can I know how many clients are connected to my server with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, embedded

I am developing an embedded device and I have a WiFi module that generate a network so my device works as a server/hotspot.
I got stuck with this problem, how do I know how many clients are connected to my network?

Comment: How do you actually connect your client to your host? The question is a bit too vague to give you a clear answer.

Comment: @GuillaumePaniagua: Via WiFi,  would have assumed [but apparently not]. Remember, WiFi isn't just a radio frequency, it's a whole set of protocols. At IP level, a lot of that is invisible/abstracted away, but it's still there.

Comment: The clients connect to me via wifi through an app we developed with Qt, this app sends commands to my embedded device which work as a server.
My embedded device has an imx6 freescale chipset with buildroot linux os and the application (for this device, that is an oven) runs on the embedded board is developed using the Qt framework.
The commands sent by the application client are for example the setting of temperature of my device.
So I want to know the IP of the client that allows me to open my socket

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as simple as counting the number of `connected` signals minus the number of `disconnected` signals.

Comment: And if I want to know the IP of the clients who were connected?

Comment: @sebba23: See `peerAddress` (and `peerPort` for their TCP port).

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable and `+1` when new connection added and `-1` when one of them disconnected.

the better way is to make QList of Sockets(clients) to access and manage them easily.

Get Clients ip like this :

```
client = nextPendingConnection();
qDebug() << client->peerAddress().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

What you propably really want to know is, how many active users of your app are connected. Not counting accidential connections by other networking software or stuck/hung apps.

I would suggest the following:

- for each command you receive from a client, you add/update a Map entry
- this map entry has the socket descriptor as key and a timestamp as value.
- Now you can regularly recheck the map and remove entries that are too old.

QMap::count() gives you the number of connected and active clients.

As further improvement, you can also attach a signal to the socket::disconnect() signal and remove the entry from the map instantly without waiting for the timeout.